# Java - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, awt, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm developing an application in Java, and I've finished writing the three main class files - however I've hit a confusing error. I'm at the moment just "attempting" to draw pixels upon the screen but my pixels array doesn't work.

I'm getting the **IndexOutOfBoundsException** in my **Render.java** even though I'm getting now warnings or errors in the code?

**Display.java**

```java
public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 190;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    
    public static Dimension DIMENSION = new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    
    public static final String TITLE = "Untitled Project";
    
    public int[] pixels;

    public boolean isRunning = false;
    
    public Thread thread;
    public Screen screen;
    public Render render;
    
    public BufferedImage img;
    
    public Display() {
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }
    
    public void start(boolean isDebug) {
        if (isRunning)
            return;
        
        isRunning = true;
        
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if (!isRunning)
            return;
        
        isRunning = false;
        
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        
        screen.render();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++)
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    
    private void tick() {
        
    }

    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            render();
            tick();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
            display.setMinimumSize(DIMENSION);
            display.setMaximumSize(DIMENSION);
            display.setPreferredSize(DIMENSION);
            
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle(TITLE);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
        display.start(true);
    }
}
```

**Render.java**

```java
public class Render {
    
    public final int width;
    public final int height;
    public final int[] pixels;
    
    public Render(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height];
    }
    
    public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
            
            int yPix = y + yOffset;
            
            for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
                int xPix = x + xOffset;
                
        ERROR -->   pixels[xPix + yPix * width] = render.pixels[x + y * render.width];
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Screen.java**

```java
public class Screen extends Render {
    
    public Render render;
    public Random random;

    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        render = new Render(256, 256);
        random = new Random();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 256 * 256; i++) {
            render.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    public void render() {
        draw(render, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 57000
at com.willajhughes.java.graphics.Render.draw(Render.java:23)
at com.willajhughes.java.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:21)
at com.willajhughes.java.Display.render(Display.java:76)
at com.willajhughes.java.Display.run(Display.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `xPix + yPix * width` or `x + y * render.width` is greater or equal than `pixels.length`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you don't say...

Comment: As quotation. Ensure that always the size are in your WIDTH and HEIGHT i.e. pixels[(xPix + yPix * width) % WIDTH] if you are not pretty sure about your calculations over the indexs.

Answer (score 3):

Your `pixels` array of is of the size `width * height`. You're attempting to access `width + height * width`. As you may imagine, that's not going to go down well with Mr. Java.

Comment: in what scenario is `xPix` not less than `width`? and `yPix` not less than `height`

Comment: That's not the issue is it? At one point, they're 1 less than `width` and `height`. And then OP attempts to reference `xPix + yPix * width`. I do apologise. It's `2` less than `width + height * width`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to super-impose a `render` of height and width

```
256, 256 (65536 pixels)
```

onto a screen of height and width

```
300, 190; (57000 pixels)
```

and you're using the same indexes for both of them.

---

maybe you want to make your render match your screen

```
render = new Render(this.width, this.height);
```

instead of hard-coding to 256x256 like you are

Answer (score 0):

The `Screen` object is created with a height of 190 pixels, but the `Render` object created in the `Screen` constructor has a height of `256` pixels.  You need to make sure you don't overwrite the bounds of your `Screen`.

Note that `WIDTH * HEIGHT = 300 * 190 = 57000`.  (From the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` defined in the `Display` class.)